# Show that $1-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n-1}}$ and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$ exists

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Show that $1-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n-1}}$ and hence that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$exists.

I’ve shown the first part but am struggling with the second bit. I’m not sure exactly what and how I have to show.

Comment: I’ve tried formatting it correctly but I can’t seem to do it for some reason.

Comment: is it correct, as I have written it?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks

Comment: I assume the question means to prove that the limit $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \bigg(1-\frac 1n \bigg)^n$$ converges?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks

Answer (score 4):

This exercise assumes you have already proved that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$$
from which you are expected to realize that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n-1})^n=e$$
whence it follows, by the algebraic manipulation in the title, that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})^n=\frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: No, all I’ve proved already is that $(1+\frac{1}{n})$ is bounded and convergent to some limit

Comment: That's wonderful, so denote the limit it converges to by $e$.

Comment: Oh I get it. So if I’ve already shown that 1 + 1/n is convergent I can show by manipulation that the required is convergent

Comment: Exactly, and the answer is the reciprocal.